# Populating checkedListBox using c# windows application

Tags: c#

I want to populate the checkedListBox control with file names from a directory which i can do now using the following code.

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(txtPath.Text.ToString());
System.IO.FileSystemInfo[] files = di.GetFileSystemInfos();
checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
```

But when the checkbox is selected, i want to get the path of file name. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the checkbox item to see which item was checked, and pull the path down from the event args passed into the event handler.

You can then use `((System.IO.FileSystemInfo)checkedListBox1.SelectedItem).FullName;` to get the full file path and name. And if needed, you can use regex to extract the path from the filename.

You can find multiple paths using the `SelectedIndices` property of the checkedListBox control.

Comment: @JD, Actually i need the path to send to a Windows media player to play the .mp3 file listed in my CheckedListBox. How can i make the WMP to play the .mp3 files one by one. ?? Thanks.

Comment: Ahh... Then you are asking a different question entirely... Use `Process.Start(path to mp3)` which will open the mp3 in the default mp3 player. If you are wanting to play a playlist style file, you will need to construct a playlist and pass that into process.start.